# Why is $\cup_{d\vert n}S_n=\{1,\dots, n\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

If $d\vert n$, let $S_d=\{\frac{xn}{d}\vert 1\leq x\leq d, (x,d)=1\}$, then $\cup_{d\vert n}S_n=\{1,\dots, n\}$.

Pf. If $1\leq m\leq n$ and $(m,n)=\frac{n}{d}$ and if $m=\frac{xn}{d}$, then $(x,d)=1$ and $1\leq x\leq \frac{dm}{n}\leq d$. Thus $m\in S_d$.

So I knew $S_d\cap S_e=\emptyset$ for $d\neq e,d\vert n,e\vert n$. The point is to show euler $\phi$ function is dirichlet convolution with $\mu$ mobius function.

Q1:What is the above proof talking about? How do I know $(m,n)=\frac{n}{d}$ all the time? Why $m=\frac{xn}{d}$ and $1\leq x\leq \frac{dm}{n}\leq d$?

Q2:What is the line of the logic here?

Comment: $\{ k \le n\} = \bigcup_{d | n} \{k \le n,gcd(k,n)=d\}=\bigcup_{d | n} \{k=m d \le n,gcd(m,n/d)=1\}$. The goal is to obtain $n = \sum_{d | n} \varphi(n/d)=\sum_{d | n} \varphi(d)$

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Let $\alpha =(m,n)$.  We know that $\alpha\mid m$ and $\alpha\mid n$, but more importantly, $\alpha$ is maximal in this regard.  So $\left(\frac{m}{\alpha},\frac{n}{\alpha}\right)=1$, because otherwise we could have increased $\alpha$ by that missing common divisor.

Now, let $d=\frac{n}{\alpha}$ and $x=\frac{m}{\alpha}$.  Some algebra then gives you $(m,n)=\frac{n}{d}$, and $m=\frac{xn}{d}$, which is how your argument defines $d$ and $x$.  Solve the latter equation for $x$ and you get $x=\frac{md}{n}$.  Hopefully, from there you can see the inequalities.

Q2: I don't know how much you know about Dirichlet convolution.  The key fact is included on the Wiki page: $f=g*1$ iff $f*g=\mu$.  So to show that $\phi=\mu*(n\mapsto n)$, it suffices to show $\phi*1=(n\mapsto n)$.

If you don't know the Wiki fact, you might want to look into how the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle gives you something called Möbius invertion.

If showing $\phi=1*(n\mapsto n)$ is tricky, well, consider this: $$n=\#(\{1,\cdots,n\})=\#\left(\bigcup_{d\mid n}{S_d}\right)$$  If $\{A_j\}_{j\in J}$ are disjoint, then $$\#\left(\bigcup_{j\in J}{A_j}\right)=\sum_{j\in J}{\#(A_j)}$$  So, if the $\{S_d\}_{d\mid n}$ are disjoint as you claim, then $$n=\sum_{d\mid n}{\#(S_d)}$$  Can you see where the proof is going now?